# Nginx doesn't work for me I get 404 Not Found

Tags: html, css, nginx, server, http-status-code-404

I'm new to programming web pages and I don't have much idea about the nginx server, it turns out that all the pages of my web, css, and js work except the pages that are inside a folder.

> 404 Not Found
> nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)

My nginx.conf code:

```
    include /etc/nginx/cleavr-conf/tecnosamuel.tk/header/*.conf;
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {   
    default upgrade; }

server {

  server_name tecnosamuel.tk;   
  root /home/cleavr/tecnosamuel.tk/current;
  charset utf-8;
  include cleavr-conf/tecnosamuel.tk/*.conf;

  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log error;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/tecnosamuel.tk-access.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

  location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    allow all;   }

location /paginas/programas {
        allow all; }


  index index.html index.htm;

  location ~* \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|js)$ {
    expires max;   }

}
```

Structure of the root folder of my website, everything works except the "paginas/programas" folder
[Structure of the root folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDGFA.png)

HELP!

Comment: Please share a latest lines of your access.log/error.log after accessing the target location

Comment: Error.log:                                                                                                                                      2022/01/31 21:27:55 [error] 11404#11404: *41 open() "/home/cleavr/tecnosamuel.tk/current/current" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.70.242.133, server: tecnosamuel.tk, request: "GET /current HTTP/1.1", host: "tecnosamuel.tk", referrer: "http://tecnosamuel.tk/current"

Comment: Acces.log:                                                                                                                                          172.70.242.133 - - [31/Jan/2022:21:27:55 +0000] "GET /current HTTP/1.1" 404 162 "http://tecnosamuel.tk/current" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; pl; rv:1.8.0.1) Gecko/20060124 Firefox/52.4.0"

Comment: You did not specify what pages are you trying to access - the full url: per logs - you are trying to access `domain.tld/current`